# `cannot find "-lgcc_s"` from gcc-3.4 on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, patch-management, g++

I'm trying to use `gcc-3.4` on the latest Ubuntu. The package is from debian snapshots.

It probably assumes different default directory structure, so for example I was forced to give it `-I /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/`, which `gcc-4` assumed implicitly.

Currently it compiles everything I gave it just fine, but it can't link. Even the simplest executable results the error:

```
$ gcc-3.4 ~/tmp.cc -o ~/tmp
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Oops! Please migrate it to unix.se, I was in the wrong site...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently you need to add the library `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1` and the compiler expect the soft link `/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/3.4.6/libgcc_s.so` pointing it to the correct place, however:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/3.4.6/libgcc_s.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 2011-05-03 04:55 /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/3.4.6/libgcc_s.so -> /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
```

And

```
$ ls /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
ls: /lib/libgcc_s.so.1: No such file or directory
```

Fix the symlink, and all will be well

```
$ sudo ln /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1  /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/3.4.6/libgcc_s.so
```

Now it works correctly!

```
$ g++-3.4   ~/tmp.cc -o ~/tmp
$
```

Comment: This is useful when working with the `davidva/gcc49` copr in Fedora. I was missing the libgcc_s.so in the right subdir `/opt/gcc-4.9.3/lib64/gcc/x86_64-fedoraunited-linux-gnu/4.9.3`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but in my case trying to install gcc 4.2 (to compile in Matlab Simulink) in Ubuntu 11.04

In my case I wrote:

```
sudo ln  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1  /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.2.3/libgcc_s.so
```

And now gcc-4.2 is compiling.

Comment: You welcome! I'm really glad you found that helpful. You can upvote the answer and the question if you like them by clicking on the "up" button, to tell other users it was useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

for me the command:

```
sudo ln /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1  /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/3.4.6/libgcc_s.so
```

does not solve the issue.

This command, instead, does solve it:

```
sudo cp /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
```

Comment: If it compiles, it should be good. Are you using latest Ubuntu?